# Surjective map inducing homeomorphism between spectra

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

> Let $\phi: A \to B$ be a surjective map of rings such that $\phi^*: \operatorname{Spec}{B} \to \operatorname{Spec}{A}$ is a homeomorphism, then $\operatorname{ker}{\phi} \subseteq \operatorname{nil}{(A)}$, where $\operatorname{nil}{(A)}$ is the nilradical of $A$.

I tried assuming that this is false, but then I got confused and didn't know where to go. I'm sure there is a nice, geometric proof of this, but I couldn't see it. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $I = \ker(\phi)$. Since $\phi \colon A \to B$ is a surjective map of rings, it follows that the canonical induced morphism $A/I \to B$ is an isomorphism, and $\phi^{\ast}$ is a closed immersion of $\operatorname{Spec}(B)$ onto the (closed) subset $V(I)$ of $\operatorname{Spec}(A)$. By assumption, $\phi^{\ast}$ is a homeomorphism, and so it follows that $V(I) = \operatorname{Spec}(A)$. In particular, this means that $I$ is contained in every prime ideal of $A$, whence $I \subset \operatorname{Nil}(A)$.